# Como hago para obtener el primer valor de una variable en JQUERY

Tags: jquery, variables

A través de este código jquery recibo el valor data de un link.

```
Skills = $('.select2').data('skills');
```

Hago alert con el valor de Skills
y me muestra lo siguiente.

```
alert(Skills)
```

Me muestra

```
 [Adaptabilidad,Aprendizaje continuo,Creatividad,]
```

Quiero acceder a los tres valores de dicha variable con Skills[0]

```
Skills[0]
```

Pero en vez de darme el valor del primer elemento "Adaptabilidad", me muestra "["

como hago para poder acceder a los valores recibidos? siempre son 3

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada el problema que se ve a simple vista es que tienes una coma `,` de más en ese array justamente al final, y por tanto no te permite acceder a datos individuales de tu arreglo

Comment: Muchas gracias, genial, la saque con substr y listo. Graciasssssssssss

Comment: que agradable saber que te pude ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Tu respuesta parece mas un comentario , cuando tengas suficiente reputación podrás hacer comentarios a las respuestas, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: lo sé, pero no podía hacer un comentario y aun así quería ayudar.